# Kerberos + Ldap Setup not working with ssh

Tags: ssh, ldap, kerberos, single-sign-on

I have a Kerberos 5 + LDAP configuration in the same server.

They both work well (I assume). Kerberos works fine when asking for a TGT.

The problem comes when I try to login from client1 to client2 via passwordless ssh... It keeps asking me for a password even if I have a valid TGT.

I post some logs and configs.

client1 ssh_config:

> Host *
>
> > GSSAPIAuthentication yes
> >     GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
> >     GSSAPIKeyExchange yes

client2 sshd_config:

> GSSAPI options
>
> > GSSAPIAuthentication yes
> >     GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
>
> Kerberos options
>
> > KerberosAuthentication yes

Trying to get a TGT from client1:

> kinit admin
>
> > Password for admin@COLOR-STEMP.COM:
>
> klist
>
> > Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
> >     Default principal: admin@COLOR-STEMP.COM
> >
> > Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
> >     23/05/13 15:35:45  24/05/13 01:35:45  krbtgt/COLOR-STEMP.COM@COLOR-STEMP.COM
> >      renew until 24/05/13 03:35:45

Trying to ssh from client1 to client2:

Client1 shell output:

> ssh admin@client2.color-stemp.com
>
> > admin@client2.color-stemp.com's password:

Client2 /var/log/auth:

> May 23 15:39:42 CLIENT2 sshd[31486]: Invalid user admin from 192.168.1.173
>   May 23 15:39:42 CLIENT2 sshd[31486]: Failed none for invalid user admin from 192.168.1.173 port 38326 ssh2

Client1 shell output:

> klist
>
> > Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
> >     Default principal: admin@COLOR-STEMP.COM
> >
> > Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
> >     23/05/13 15:35:45  24/05/13 01:35:45  krbtgt/COLOR-STEMP.COM@COLOR-STEMP.COM
> >      renew until 24/05/13 03:35:45
> >     23/05/13 15:40:24  24/05/13 01:35:45  host/client2.color-stemp.com@COLOR-STEMP.COM
> >      renew until 24/05/13 03:35:45

As you can see, CLIENT2 ssh2 is not even trying to authenticate against the kerberos server. But Kerberos is giving client1 the TGT for client2.

I have checked connection or DNS issues... It is all fine.

Any help? thanks in advance...

UPDATE

@Steve: I have checked /etc/pam.d/sshd and looks like there is no kerberos config there... however this is what I have in nsswitch.conf:

`#`pre_auth-client-config # passwd:         compat
passwd: files ldap
`#`pre_auth-client-config # group:          compat
group: files ldap
`#`pre_auth-client-config # shadow:         compat
shadow: files ldap

With the command pam-auth-update I have selected Kerberos Authentication too.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you checked what PAM is trying to use with ssh? at least in CentOS it will use what is in /etc/pam.d/sshd. You may also want to look at your /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: What does `getent passwd admin` say on client2? Is authentication failing because the client2 doesn't think that admin is a valid user?

Comment: getent passwd admin does not shows anything... seems to me that client2 is not even trying to authenticate "admin" user against the kerberos... :-(

Answer (score 1):

client2 does not have an account named admin therefore all attempt to authenticate to that non-existent account will fail. `sshd` isn't going to bother doing GSSAPI for an account that doesn't exit.

If this is account is supposed to exist locally, you need to create it with `useradd`. If it exists in LDAP, then make sure you `nss-ldap`/`nss-ldapd` is appropriately configured (usually `/etc/ldap.conf`).